# CSS isn't wokring from style sheet link

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I've tested this in both FF(29) and IE(11) and they both act the same way.

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MiCapture</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="SS1.css" name="main_sheet">  
</head>

<body>
<div id="banner"><img src="https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/bobleah/resource/sky.gif"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my CSS file "SS1.css"

```
<style  type="text/css">

          #banner {
             margin-left:auto; 
             margin-right:auto; 
             width:1000px;  
          }

          #banner img { 
             max-width:1000px; 
             max-height:300px; 
          }

</style>
```

When I load my page, my image does not get centered, but if I change my HTML and include my CSS directly in my code, it does get centered. Why does the link not work?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MiCapture</title>
  <style  type="text/css">

          #banner {
             margin-left:auto; 
             margin-right:auto; 
             width:1000px;  
          }

          #banner img { 
             max-width:1000px; 
             max-height:300px; 
          }

</style>    
</head>

<body>
<div id="banner"><img src="https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/bobleah/resource/sky.gif"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the css file resides in the same directory as your html file? and also use lower case file names.

Comment: the stylesheet does not need `</style>` tags and ^

Comment: Remove the `<style>` tags from the CSS file.

Comment: Last1Here, post as answer, so I can give you credit (since you answered first).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stylesheet file does not need `<style></style>` tags which you have included in it, removing them will solve your issue.